# A companion to McCawley's The Syntactic Phenomena of English?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

What would be a good syntax book to read as companion to James McCawley's *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*?

As great as McCawley's book is, at times it makes for challenging reading, particularly for those of us with no formal linguistic background.

So, is there a syntax book that works particularly well with McCawley's work? Sometimes, reading two (or more books) on the same subject can help you get a better grasp of things.

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested solely in studying transformational grammar? McCawley's 1998 work is well-respected, but not aimed at beginners. You might consider studying straightforward traditional descriptive grammar.

Comment: I want to avoid *traditional grammar,* and I didn't want to make my question specific to *transformational grammar* because McCawley himself refused to give a "name" to the syntactic phenomena he was describing in his 1998 book.  So, labels aside, I'm just interested in a syntax book (or books) that goes well with *The Syntactic Phenomena* (traditional grammar excluded). Still, if what works best is *transformational grammar,* then that's where I'll focus my search. Thanks.

Comment: Chomsky's *Aspects of the Theory of Syntax* is good.  Despite your aversion to traditional grammar, I like Otto Jespersen's *Philosophy of Grammar*.  (McCawley wrote about Jespersen's *Analytic Syntax* here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/412288.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents )

Comment: I can recommend _Analysing English Sentences_ by Andrew Radford. The following Amazon link contains the table of contents and a few pages from the introduction which will help you determine if this is what you are looking for. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Analysing-Sentences-Cambridge-Textbooks-Linguistics/dp/0521669707/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1528221034&sr=8-1&keywords=radford+sentences